Relative motion between two points on a rotating disc
Consider two children A and B sitting on diametrically opposite points of a merry go round rotating about its centre. Suppose A and B are facing each other. As seen from A, B never seems to move and neither rotates about him. However, if we calculate the relative velocity of B w.r.t. A by usual formula ( http://emweb.unl.edu/NEGAHBAN/EM373/note15/note.htm ) or by subtraction of velocities, it comes out to be 2Rω.
Where am I going wrong? This question has bugged me for a long.time and I have not found suitable explanation to this dilemma. Someone please clarify from a practical and mathematical standpoint.

You are correct, in a frame of reference centered on one children, comoving with him and ALSO ROTATING with him, the other child would be at rest.
But if you center the frame of reference on one child and take the orientation of the axis to be fixed with respect to the world, than the other child will drow a circumference around the first child.
The radius of this circumference will be the distance of the two guys ($2R$). At the same time, the period for one complete revolution will be the same of the time for one complete rotation (the period $T$), so also the angular speed will be the same. Since the tangential velocity of the circular motion is given by $\omega R$, and the radius of the circle described by the second child around the first one is $2R$, you have the final velocity $2R\omega$.

Thank you so much for your reply....I am still unable wrap my head around it (sorry for my ignorance). Can you explain it a bit more, in simple words?
